# Get Object property value calling it with string

Tags: javascript

I pass some object to my function. I have some array of predefined variables. I need so set specific attribute in `SomeObject` (which name is in the array) to the value of property of passed object. How can I access 'em?

```
    function a(MyObject) {
    var list = ["Auto", "Cook", "West", "Vodka"];

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    SomeObject.getSomeAttribute(list[i]).setValue(MyObject.list[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

I tried 2 ways, none of 'em works in js:

- `var a = MyObject[list[i]];`
- `var a = MyObject.list[i];`

I understand that there's wrong syntax, but I have no idea how can I do this.

Comment: `MyObject[list[i]]` is exactly what you want.

Comment: Strange magic, now it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as easy as doing

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
youObject[list[i]] = somevalue;
}
```